# Laravel Submit Form with Toggle Checkbox

Tags: php, html, laravel

There is a switch button in the form. My purpose of using this switch button is to determine whether it is passive or active. When I submit the submit form, its value is "on". What I want to do is to go to the controllers as "passive" if its value is "active" if it is selected, and write it to the database like that.

**Add standard form only, not ajax**

HTML Code below

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <span class="switch">
    <label>
      <input name="status" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="form-text text-muted">{{ __('Is it active?') }}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Checkbox value **wont pass** to controller, if the checkbox is **not checked**

Comment: You can use  `$model->status = ($request->status) ?? 1 : 0 ;`

Answer (score 2):

In your Controller should check it in this way

```
if ($request->status == 'on') {
   here you code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether the checkbox is `checked`, then the answer provided by [@Aian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67659053/281278) will work. You can also use `has()` on the `Request` object to determine if a property is present:

```
if ($request->has('status')) {
    // 'status' property present, do something
}
```

If you want to send the value `passive` to your controller rather than use the default `on` value, then you need to provide that on your `input`:

```
<input name="status" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="passive" />
```

Now if your checkbox is `checked`, the value of `$request->status` will be `passive` rather than `on`.